# How to use .jks (Java keystore) file to make an HTTP request in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have been shared with a `.jks` file and a `private key`, and I need to make an HTTP post request using `requests` module.

I went through the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) module and found that I can make the request something like this -

```
requests.post(<url>, <req xml>, headers={k: v}, cert=('/path/client.cert', '/path/client.key'))
```

But my file has `.jks` extension. I tried running the request like below -

```
requests.post(<url>, <req xml>, headers={k: v}, cert=('/path/file.jks', 'my-private-key'))
```

I get this error -

> OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line'),
>   ('SSL rou tines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file', 'PEM lib')]

Is it possible to use `.jks` file to make an HTTP request? Any suggestion how can I correct this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JKS is the old and outdated java keystore format, newer ones would be PKCS#12.

You could use a lib like Pyjks or the java keytool to extract the certificates you need and put those into pem encoded files to use with requests. (https://github.com/kurtbrose/pyjks)

Or you could dive into urllib3 internals (https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/util/ssl_.py) and create the ssl context yourself, similar to the example shown in the pyjks documentation.